# How to create a page which loads content based off of the url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to create an easy product display system. I have a database of products which we are displaying on a single /shop.php page, it just lists all the products. But we're at the stage now where we need to have urls linking to products and so each product needs its own page. AKA /products/product1..product2..product3, but really in the backend it's only a product.php file which looks at the incoming/products/product url and creates the page via just that url, AKA the product SKU or ID or whatever primary key, would probably have to use the name because SKU urls look a bit weird. We are using .htaccess to redirect urls such as /shop /home /aboutus so urls such as /products/Bianco needs to display the product page for Bianco.

I hope you can help, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is pretty straightforward.

On the Shop page, the product url would be : `http:website.com/products/Bianco`

And In your php script for the products page : `products.php`, you would do something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['product_name'])) {

    //filter and fetch the product name and get the product details from the database

} else {

   //404

}
```

The trick being, Friendly urls convert `http:website.com/products/Bianco` to `http:website.com/products.php?product_name=Bianco`

So, your script would still get the GET variable, which you then use to fetch the product details from the product database.

Comment: could I just ask how you would post that GET variable from the href link? Or I could link it to a javascript click listener and AJAX it?

Comment: Ohhh you create the urls with .php?product_id

Comment: Yeah, you just create a product.php page and then check if a GET variable is set, same way you would've if the url's weren't made friendly. The rewrite rules allows you to redirect a url like this: _http://website.com/products/Bianco_ to the php page on the server (products.php) for processing it.

Comment: the url needs to be website.com/products.Bianco?sku=SKUCODE right?

Comment: If you were NOT using friendly url's the url would be: _website.com/products.php?product_name=Bianco&product_code=SKUCODE_ But if you are using Rewriterules (Apache) or Rewrite(Nginx) you just make it _website.com/products/Bianco/SKUCODE_ and let the rewrite rules to redirect it to the non-friendly url above.

Comment: For example, Take the url: _https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/_ . If reddit hadn't set url rewrite rules, this would've been the url which you would need to type in: _https://www.reddit.com/subreddit.php?subreddit_name=programming_ (i.e if it was made using php)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use iFrames.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp